# Visual Morphs | SVG vs Canvas vs Other

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a bit of a strange question but I thought I'd see if it's been done before.

I want to morph one div element (and all it's inner elements) in to another - visually.  This I imagine is very complicated and I could not find a demo on google.

I'm not talking about transitions or just varying CSS properties.  For example not [this](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/mootools-morph.php) moo tools demo or [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=scriptaculous_7) scriptaculous demo.

I can't even imagine how this would be done.  Any ideas.  For example suppose each div element was just a picture, then this would equate to morphing from one picture to another.

Seems like there are a lot of libraries that do morphs...but these just vary CSS properties.

**Related**

http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a clear conception of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: sounds like I know that you don't know what I know :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, perhaps this:

Make both elements, e1 and e2, cross-morph into each-other.

To get a replace effect e1 could have an initial opacity of 0 (target 1) and e2 an opacity of 1 (target 0). At some point, if following the same easing/interpolation functions (but coming from different sides: e1->e2.orig and e2->e1.orig) then the values should "cross paths" ..

A better morph would do this recursively (and simultaneously) for each element in e1 that mapped to an element in e2 (e.g. imagine a circle in square turning into a square in a circle), but that is significantly more complicated.

Comment: JavaScript has access to the DOM and CSS and some ways of drawing primitives and curves (e.g. Canvas or SVG) ..

Answer (score 2):

There are many methodologies of visually morphing one element from one to another.  Asking how to visually morph a "div" element is probably the wrong point of view.  There are a number of JavaScript toolkits to accomplish "visual morphing" of one kind or another.

Some examples are...

- One interesting example is the [WebKit Clock](http://onotakehiko.com/webkitclock/#bangalore) This uses no images, just CSS, JavaScript, SVG and a few other elements.  Of course as it uses SVG it is less than useless in IE8 and below.
- One JavaScript library that does work in a cross-browser way is [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/)  This [page](http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html) here is a decent example of "visual morphing".  It does work with IE8 and below as it converts the SVG code to VML, although VML performance is horrendous and even Microsoft is deprecating it in favor of SVG for IE9.
- Even older libraries like <strike>[Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/gallery/)</strike> have some interesting visual tricks up their sleeves.  Sorry Prefuse is Java, I was thinking of [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/)

In short you don't have to wait 10 years to accomplish some really neat visual trickery, but you may have to take a different approach.

Comment: ...and in the mobile space, SVG isn't supported by most Android devices currently in use (possibly as much as 85% of them)

Comment: @MattCoughlin I find that curious as Google is one of the biggest proponents of open standards like SVG.  Oddly enough the examples work well on my iPhone, go figure.

Comment: Yeah, Google waited an uncharacteristically long time before supporting SVG (Android 3.0 and up). It's unfortunate.

Comment: @Matt...in general is Canvas more supported?